# Visual Studio 2019 Copy Paste Broken (Clipboard History??)

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 has suddenly started to copy/paste strange text.

I have a basic `.cshtml` file in a Core 3.1 web application.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Lorem Ipsum";
}

<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

Steps to reproduce strange behavior:

- On Line 2 Hightlight `ViewData`
- Control+C

[image]

- Go to end of Line 2
- Press Enter
- Control+V

[image]

I get some strange junk every time.  It's really annoying and I'd like to know how to make it stop doing this!  Does anyone have an idea?

**Update1:**
I've been reading about clipboard history.  Shift+Control+V

You can see I have two items in the list that seem to be the source of my pasting junk.  I cannot figure out how I even copied something into there.  I also cannot find documentation on how to clear it.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you paste that text into some other application? What happens if you copy text from some other application? Does it occur with other file types? Support for VS 2019 might also be considered off-topic (not sure).

Comment: I don't get this behavior in other applications.  I've tested in apps like word and notepad+ and everything seems to be ok. I have found that I can click Shift+Control+V and a clipboard history appears.  It has the junk in it that keeps pasting.  But I can't see how to clear it or turn it off.  I will post a picture.

Comment: Please see update.

Comment: I am experiencing this too.. since the latest update. It seems not to be a paste problem as, if you copy something from outside VS, it pastes fine. I think it's the text-selection + copy issue.

Comment: I am experiencing it in .cshtml's only as of right now.  Essentially, if I copy any HTML within the .cshtml it pastes as expected.  If I copy any c# or razor within the .cshtml it pastes seemingly random text (nothing I have copied previously).

Comment: @nokturnal  and JanusKampHansen - agreed to both comments.  Same behavior I'm experiencing.  I'm on Visual Studio 2019 latest version 16.7.4 and it's still doing it.

Comment: @cmill I have created an issue with Microsoft, please upvote: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1201185/visual-studio-2019-v1674-copy-paste-not-working-co.html

Comment: @nokturnal  Thank you!  I upvoted your Microsoft issue.  I hope we hear something soon.  It's really annoying to a smooth workflow for something as basic as copy/paste.

Comment: @cmill I just updated to 16.7.5 and the issue remains.

Comment: @nokturnal - same here 16.7.5  - As annoying as ever today.  It definitely appears to happen only when inside `@{ //code here }` blocked section .cshtml file.

Comment: @nokturnal - I stumbled across this today.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/new-experimental-razor-editor-for-visual-studio/  It appears to copy/paste as expected.  I will work with this today before I say it solve it.

Comment: After only 5 min using...it gets boo hiss boo from me.  The code snippets in JavaScript sections are dead.  eg. Type if, tab, tab and you should get an if block.  It does not work with this experimental feature turned on!  That's worse than copy/paste being broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft acknowledged and corrected the issue.   See the link in the original post's comments to Microsoft forum.